# Use ExpectedException with Kotlin

Tags: java, junit, kotlin

I've declared an expected exception with Kotlin:

```
@Rule
public var exception = ExpectedException.none()
```

Now my integration test case:

```
@Test
@Transactional
fun authorize_withInvalidToken()
{
    val response = controller.authorize(networkType = "facebook", oauthToken = "", oauthTokenSecret = null)
    exception.expect(UnauthorizedException::class.java)

}
```

I get the error:

```
org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @Rule 'exception' must be public.
```

Is there a way to fix this? For now I'll just use manual try/catch/assert

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Annotate the exception property with `@JvmField`:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var exception = ExpectedException.none()
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However I couldn't then get it to catch the exception - not sure why. I went back try/catch/assert.

Comment: The call to exception.expect() must be **before** the code that throws the exception.

Comment: “public” is unnecessary here as it is the default for field/property visibility.

Comment: If you are curious why it is because in the Java code `exception` is converted to a private field then public `getException()` and `setException()` methods are generated. The decompiler is your friend, especially when reflection is being used.